# Delete geometry using index in geometry node

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to delete geometry based on the index number like I want to every third index and it should go until points (curve/mesh) end. Also, what could I do if I want to use any other index instead of the third one?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this node setup to delete every 3rd face. I used faces here, that you can clearer see, what happens. Just change the delete geometry node from face to point to delete points.

[image]

[image]

Just change the value in modulo from 3 to any other value you want e.g. 4 to delete every 4th point.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. It is really helpful.

Comment: glad i could help

Answer (score 2):

@Chris [has answered](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273658/35559), but here's a little group to explore modulo-selection, including options to invert and offset your selection.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing your the files that's really helpful.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, double check their nodes, and also try offsetting Index with a negative number instead of adding. In my case I changed math node to subtract and offset the index with numbers running up to the count of the vertices it had.